# Get base64 code from encoded string

Tags: google-chrome, base64

I want to get Image from this Url `http://smartcard.rmto.ir:7003/tto/webservice/get_img/2490172,PICTURE,PICTURE123` but it returns encoded String and cant be encoded by Base64 library , but in chrome developer mode in network tab response cannot be encoded but content of preview tab can be encoded successfully.
the question is how can i convert string in response to string in preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by using Volley `ImageLoader` class